# How to fetch the records from Hive table where the month = current month else month = previous month (current month – 1)?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a situation where I need to retrieve the data from Hive table where month = current month. If current month data is not available I need to fetch from previous month. How can we achieve this case in Hive query.

Is my query correct?

```
Select emp_name, emp_number,
case when emonth IS NULL then concat(year(current_date()),'-' ,month(current_date())-1) else emonth end
FROM db.emptable
where emonth =concat(year(current_date()),'-' ,month(current_date()))
```

I am not sure of above query because, if I don't have current month records in the table CASE condition simply assigning previous month in the ***emonth column***. 
But I need to have the validation if month is current month fetch else fetch previous month data.

Answer (score 0):

month(string date) can be used to fetch month from any date stamp.

So you can try:

Select emp_name, emp_number,
case when emonth IS NULL then month(add_months(current_date(), -1))
else emonth 
end
FROM db.emptable

Comment: Hi Pawan, you mean we no need to handle where clause? It's not very clear actually. I make it simple. I need to fetch emp data where month is current month, if no data available to current month, I need to fetch from previous month.

Answer (score 0):

Filter data using row_number:

```
select  emonth, emp_name, emp_number
 from
(
select emonth, emp_name, emp_number,
       row_number() over (partition by emp_number order by case when emonth= substr(current_date(),1,7) then 1 else 2 end ) rn
  from db.emptable
where emonth >= substr(add_months(concat(substr(current_date(),1,7),'-01'),-1),1,7) --prev month
)s
where rn=1 -- If current month is absent, previous month rn=1
```

write partition by clause in the row_number as you need to calculate it correctly. In my answer row_number will be calculated for each emp_number.